# How to make a condtion in a a lambda expression when assigning a value

Tags: c#, sharepoint, lambda, expression, linq-to-sharepoint

I am trying to assign a value to my item but i need to put a condition because the id changes depending of the language.

```
Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>[] fieldsToRetreive 
    = new Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>[] {
        item => item["A"], //
        item => item["B"], //
        item => item["C"], //
        item => item["D"], //
        item => item["E"], //
        item => item["F"], //
        item => item["G"], //
        item => item["H"],
    },
```

I am try to do something similar to this:

```
item => if(item["I"] != null){item=>item["I"]}else{item=>item["J"])
```

UPDATE:
Here is more of the code of the function

```
private List<ListItem> FindItemsWithContentType(List list, string contentTypeId, DateTime? notOlderThan = null)
        {
            DateTime searchDate = new DateTime(1990, 01, 01);

            if (notOlderThan.HasValue && notOlderThan.Value.Date == DateTime.Today)
                searchDate = notOlderThan.Value.AddDays(-1); // Sharepoint does not take time into account, so we roll back to yesterday if today
            else
                notOlderThan = searchDate;
            string date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(searchDate, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"); // could also be like: "<Today OffsetDays=\"-7\" />"

            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery()
            {
                ViewXml = string.Format("<View><Query><Where><And><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>{0}</Value></BeginsWith><Gt><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Gt></And></Where></Query></View>", contentTypeId, date)
            };

            ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

            Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>[] fieldsToRetreive = new Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>[] {
                                                                                                                item => item["A"],                                                                                                                 item => item["B"],                                                                                                               item => item["C"],                                                                                                             item => item["D"],                                                                                                              item => item["E"],                                                                                                                item => item["F"],                                                                                                               item => item["G"],                                                                                                                 item => item["H"],                                                                                                            item => item["I"] ?? item["J"]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            };


            // Making sure we load the content of the item fields
            this.AppOnlyContext.Load(items, i => i.Include(fieldsToRetreive));
            this.AppOnlyContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: That's a conditional expression, often called a "ternary" because it has three operands: `item => (item["I"] != null)  ? item=>item["I"] : item=>item["J"];`

Comment: `item => item["I"] != null ? item["I"] : item["J"]`. Or shorter `item => item["I"] ?? item["J"]`

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am getting the following error: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between "lambda expression" and "lambda expression"

Comment: @alphonsoCulano Please show the code that's giving you that error. But you should really use the null-coalescing operator suggested by DK and Racil, which I neglected due to advanced senile dementia.

Comment: @RacilHilan  , i am getting the following error -"The query expression '(item.get_Item(\"I\") ?? item.get_Item(\"J\"))' is not supported."}Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidQueryExpressionException when using the coalescing operator

Comment: Okie, now I'm actually unclear of the OP's goal. Looks like it might be something like performance optimization by run-time code construction picking one of the lambda expressions and reusing it later in the code. A larger example of how `fieldsToRetreive ` is (supposed to be) used would be helpful as this could turn into a simple OO-design problem or a legit intricate code-building case.

Comment: Yes, the `??` operator is relatively new in C# and I don't know the version you're using, so try my first suggestion `item => item["I"] != null ? item["I"] : item["J"]`.

Comment: @RacilHilan i am getting the same error: -  $exception {"The query expression 'IIF((item.get_Item(\"I\") != null), item.get_Item(\"I\"), item.get_Item(\"J\"))' is not supported."} Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidQueryExpressionException

Comment: I don't have `IIF` in my comment, where did that come from? It looks like the VB `IIf()` operator combined with the C# trinary operator. That makes no sense.

Comment: Hi Racil, this is c#. I am justy copy pasting the error code :(

Comment: @alphonsoCulano Can you share the full context here? It looks like you're using [Linq to Sharepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee535491(v%3Doffice.14)), is that correct? So it's going to be translating your C# LINQ expression into some other language that Shartepoint actually uses internally. VB perhaps, VBA...? I've added the linq-to-sharepoint tag. You're the 27th question on that subject we've seen. Congratulations!

Comment: @EdPlunkett +1. This looks precisely like LINQ not being able to turn C# expression into Sharepoint-compatible VBA. I didn't work with that stack specifically - so can only guess here that it could be helped by e.g. upgrading sharepoint version to the one LINQ expects, using a different sharepoint communication library or just simplifying request logic and doing all the processing back in c#.

Comment: The solution with Linq to SQL is generally to identify the translatable subset of C#, and stick to that. Unfortunately your subset may not be so well documented. It could possibly be as simple as `item => { if (item != null) then return item["I"] else return item["J"]; }`.

Comment: Like EdPlunkett said, it looks like your code is being translated to an internal VB code. Your best bet is to search for a setting to change the default internal language to C#. If no such a setting exists, consider changing your code to VB. If that's not an option either, I'm afraid you're stuck with only using expressions that work in both VB and C#, and that's very limited.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's not how you write it in VB :). If you look at the error, you'll notice that `!= null` was not translated to VB, and VB has neither `!=` nor `null`, so your line will not likely work unless it magically starts translating those two. This is how it should be written in VB `item => If(item["I"] IsNot Nothing, item["I"], item["J"])`. I didn't change the square brackets to parentheses which is what VB uses because in the error it seems that the brackets were translated correctly. Alphonso, could you try this line above?

Comment: Or it can be written with another version of `If()` like this: `item => If(item["I"], item["J"])`. Try this one too, it looks much better with less crazy mixing of VB and C#.